# Multithreading in Swift 3 with GCD

Tags: multithreading, swift3

I'm working on a webservice based app and I've come to a crashing hault due to sending requests too quickly to the webservice.  I simply can not getting GCD working in Swift 3 and I'm scratching my head.  I've decided to dumb it down and just try loading 4 web images to a web view in order.  Based on everything I'm seeing online the following code should work, but it is still freezing the UI until all four images load. What am I doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

let imageURLs = ["http://www.planetware.com/photos-large/F/france-paris-eiffel-tower.jpg", "http://adriatic-lines.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/canal-of-Venice.jpg", "http://hd-wall-papers.com/images/wallpapers/hi-resolution-pictures/hi-resolution-pictures-5.jpg", "http://hd-wall-papers.com/images/wallpapers/hi-resolution-pictures/hi-resolution-pictures-1.jpg"]

class Downloader {

class func downloadImageWithURL(_ url:String) -> UIImage! {

    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)
    return UIImage(data: data!)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView3: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView4: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var sliderValueLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func didClickOnStart(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "syncQueue")

    serialQueue.sync{
        let img1 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[0])
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            self.imageView1.image = img1
        })
    }

    serialQueue.sync{
        let img2 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[1])
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            self.imageView2.image = img2
        })
    }

    serialQueue.sync{
        let img3 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[2])
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            self.imageView3.image = img3
        })
    }

    serialQueue.sync{
        let img4 = Downloader.downloadImageWithURL(imageURLs[3])
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            self.imageView4.image = img4
        })
    }




    }
    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        self.sliderValueLabel.text = "\(sender.value * 100.0)"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> freezing the UI

Because you are calling `serialQueue.sync`. You almost *never* want to call `sync`, and in this case you certainly don't. Use `async` instead.

Comment: That was it!  Wow, I was close.  It won't let me accept this answer for another 10 minutes, but I will.  Thank you so much!